# Cloud Functions for Firebase Notification

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fire a notification using Cloud Functions for Firebase. I can get it to console log stating a message has been fired, but can't actually get the notification to work in the browser. Can anyone see a flaw?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.newMessageAlert = functions.database.ref('/messages/{message}').onWrite((event) => {
    const message = event.data.val();

const getTokens = admin.database().ref('users').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    const tokens = [];
    snapshot.forEach((user) => {
        const token = user.child('token').val();
        if (token) tokens.push(token);
    });
    return tokens;
});

const getAuthor = admin.auth().getUser(message.uid);

Promise.all([getTokens, getAuthor]).then(([tokens, author]) => {
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: `Hot Take from ${author.displayName}`,
            body: message.content,
            icon: author.photoURL
        }
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then((resp) =>{
        console.log("IT WORKED", resp);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Does the response contain any error?

Comment: Hi @al. No, no error. I can console log the message but just can't get it to appear as a notification.

Comment: I see. AFAICT, the cloud function code looks fine. Possibly more on the handling of the message on the client side.

Comment: What happens if you try to log `tokens`?  Does it contain what you expect ti to contain?

Comment: Did you solve it?, I have the same problem it appears to be working but the notification does not come to the device. The notification also does not appear on the notifications log from firebase console... But sending a notification to a device (from firebase console) works... Very strange.

Comment: @bones.felipe did u solved it ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Abhishek. No, I didn't.